# Google Maps Activity Error: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, android

Hi so I have a button that is supposed to bring me from one activity to another. These activities are both the google map activity but whenever I try to press on the button and switch activities, it doesn't work and I get this message in the debug panel.

MapActivity.java:

```
   package com.example.reportingapp_;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Button for Map
        Button buttonMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
        buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openLocationReport();

            }
        });

        }

    public void openLocationReport() {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, LocationReport.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

The message I get in the debug panel is

```
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe88247b0, tid 19317
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fd2cf000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8804b50, tid 19359
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe8805d40: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
W/Gralloc4: allocator 3.x is not supported
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8805d40: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xb78c70f0) (first time)
    eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8805d40: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xb78c70f0) (first time)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/e.reportingapp: Unsupported class loader
W/e.reportingapp: Unsupported class loader
W/e.reportingapp: JNI critical lock held for 22.804ms on Thread[1,tid=19265,Runnable,Thread*=0xdaac2a10,peer=0x70efdc88,"main"]
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 201817022
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8827920, tid 19539
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe8827610: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8827610: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xb78da710) (first time)
    eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8827610: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xb78da710) (first time)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:61315', transport: 'socket'
```